# Always need to empty browser history

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

I have a C#/.NET website on my local machine that I use to test.

Everytime I run the website in Internet Explorer 7, I have to empty the browser history or it will stay logged on as the previous person.

How do I make it so it lets me log in without having to empty the history every single time I want to test?

Comment: How is user authentication/authorisation implemented in your application. That is the key question. Without this piece of information it is difficult to give you an exact answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your login information is stored in the session and that sets a cookie in IE7. So you don't have to clear the whole history - just a session cookie for the site. 
Alternatively you could implement 'logout' functionality in your app.

Answer (score 1):

Since the issue exists only in your development environment, a **workaround** would be to use a browser that implements a 'private' mode such as *Google Chrome's incognito mode* or *Microsoft Internet Explorer 8's InPrivate mode*

These browsers, when operating in these 'private' modes do not keep the cookies and temporary internet files after you close the window **which should solve your issue.**

However, it should be kept in mind that these browsers **might not be fully compatible** with the website you are developing.

**Moreover, you should provide more information regarding the implementation of your website's authentication and your website in general if a more permanent solution is to be reached.**